# Pain in the toes while cycling using clipless shoes

Tags: clipless, pain

I am not sure why I get a pain in my toes. After some 75 km of cycling, I don't find it right. The blood starts to clot in the tip of the toes.
After I lift my legs while lying down, it gets alright.
I am not new to cycling. I have done a lot of cycling but not much with my clipless shoes.
I feel that the shoes are sharp in front end to add to the aerodynamics.
Should I change my shoes? What should I check for while buying clipless shoes?

Comment: If you previously used toe clips you will habitually push your feet forward, to keep them in the clips.  Try to relax your feet a bit in this regard.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to getting the right size shoes. Make sure the cleats are adjusted correctly. It sounds like you're getting something similar to "black toe" experienced by hikers and runners. It's usually caused by their toes getting jammed to the front of their shoes (imagine walking down a steep incline).

If your cleats are too far back people tend to point their toes down while pedaling. The cleats should be centered under the ball of your foot, depending on riding style/ experience, they can be moved forward or back by a few millimeters. in a perfect world every shop would have professional fitment analysis to take the guess work out of all this. This also happens if the saddle is too high, people don't realize this when making the switch to clipless pedals.

What I use to tell clients when buying new clipless shoes is to make sure they are snug around your arch and heel, but you're able to wiggle your toes comfortably.

Comment: There is still debate about optimal shoe position, many are moving towards lining up the pedal axel to fall between the head of the 1st and 5th metatarsal bones.  This seems to be especially important for longer feet (which may need more support).  The 1st head is commonly referred to as the "ball of the foot."

Comment: I have moved the cleat a bit up according to your suggestion. Let me check that and come back here. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure your shoes are the correct size.

When I first started serious riding, I got cycling shoes in a size 42, and they were fine. As I continued through high school and college, I continued to get size 42, even though my feet would be sore by the end of a ride. Finally, my last year of school, I got a new pair in a size 43, and it made all the difference in the world.

Comment: I went through the ordeal of trying on shoes in the store, imagining what they would be like to ride in. I assumed that standing and walking in the shoe in the store would flatten my foot more than when I was wearing the shoe on the bike. I was wrong. Shoes standing in the store should feel too big. My experience.

Answer (score 0):

I have this - but I know my shoes are on the small side.

1. wear thin socks.  Gives that extra bit of space.
2. before riding, push your heel all the way back to the rear of the shoe and then tighten the top strap/buckle quite tightly.  Leave the front strap or straps quite loose.

You can also help by trying to pedal with your feet a bit more level and avoid pointing them downward.